# filter list view web part from url like search

Tags: 2013, list-view, url, list-view-web-part

On a List view web part, I know that passing parameters to the url applies a filter, similar to this

```
http://server/site/Lists/Links/AllItems.aspx?FilterField1=DocumentID&FilterValue1=650
```

You can pass multiple fields like this

```
http://server/site/Lists/Links/AllItems.aspx?FilterField1=DocumentID&FilterValue1=650&FilterField2=Title&FilterValue2=Link650
```

I also see from a similar question that its possible to filter for multiple values, although I have not tried this yet.

```
http://server/site/Lists/Links/AllItems.aspx?FilterName=DocumentID&FilterMultiValue=650;632;33
```

What I want to do though, is filter in the url by a search value. So if you imagine in a Links library, the user types in a search field 'mylink', then I pass the appropriate field values to the url, and the list should be refined to show any items containing mylink... e.g. mylink1, mylink2, mylink3

Is this possible to do by refining the url, I know the list view web part has an out of the box search which does this but it doesn't seem to work on one of our On Premise SP2013 sites, although it works fine on our SharePoint Online site.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible, judging by the lack of answers, the out of the box search feature on the List View web part should be okay for this, however we are having some issues with this so will have to debug that problem